# Rendering extjs component to html tpl

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

i have a simple template:

```
tpl: '<table><tr><td>{LogicalCondition}</td></tr></table>',
```

Instead of `{LogicalCondition}` I want to place extjs component (dynamically).

(http://jsfiddle.net/4t458yxo/2/)

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.ux.form.BoolDisplayField', {
        extend: 'Ext.Component',
        alias: 'widget.booldisplayfield',
        tpl: '<table><tr><td>{LogicalCondition}</td></tr></table>',       
        constructor: function (config) {
            this.initConfig(config);
            this.callParent(arguments);
        },
        applyValue: function (v) {
            if (v) {
                this.update({
                    //instead of combo i am getting [object object]
                    LogicalCondition: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
                        store: ["a"],
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        displayField: 'name'

                    })
                });
            }
            return v;
        }
    });
    var c = Ext.create('MyApp.view.ux.form.BoolDisplayField', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        value: false
    });

c.setValue(true);
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Do you want to be able to place any component depending on data value or do you just need a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Ext (X)Template does not allow components in its data but plain objects or arrays are assumed. Ext when processing the new data for the template (`update` call) understands "LogicalCondition" as text - you get object (combo instance) converted to text ([object object]).

Most likely, there is another way how to achieve what you want, (X)Template/data is obviously not the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a controller? Create the component you need dynamically when you need it and just use add() to a Container with table layout?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/?mobile=/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer#method-add